# t() as in drupal

Tags: meteor

t() is an extremely useful function in drupal but I can't figure out how to do it in meteor.

The problem is that template parsing function is ran client side but you don't want the ability to trigger inserts there.

How can you fix this?

t(): http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/t/7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I sent to you:

```
 https://gist.github.com/2579561
```

However to detect client side what strings you have not translated you will have to open up writes client side as you said, even through a convoluted process like using Meteor.call(). This will however not be an issue if its just an admin table and has no functionality, you could even list the template called and verify the tag exists there too.

There are other mechanisms that you could do this with, reading the template code on the server could be one. I'm pretty sure it wouldn't be hard to get handlebars on the server to do this and have similar translate functions on the server looking for missing tags in languages you don't have.

Beyond that eventually you will have some form of server side rendering process but currently it doesn't exist built in. So personally I would opt for the client side writes through the Meteor.calls and just filter out the spam (Which in the time frame I don't think would happen) then move to the server side approach when you can / if it becomes an issue (As if it was just an interface collection for admins it would just be an admin overhead in spam not actually a security risk).

Comment: Fair enough, that' s pretty much what we came to on IRC. Although accepting the false inputs is not a security issue in this case it's still a nuisance I'd like to avoid so I'll find some workaround for now until Handlebars is supported server side.